# Generators in the sense of the theory of canonical transformations

Tags: conformal-geometry, canonical-transformation, poisson-geometry, conformal-field-theory

I was studying this paper [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4403)  and I’m stuck at eq.13. I have really no idea why they wrote that equation. I’m especially confused about $K=pq$ and $X=q^2$.
Maybe I have to study something about that, if so could you tell me what to study?

Thanks for your time